# Getting error while trying to print the numbers

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Arraylist1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>();

        System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
        while (in.hasNext()) {

            inputs.add(in.nextDouble());


        }
        System.out.println(inputs);

     }


 }
```

When I enter the input as `1 2 3 4 5 q` I am getting error as:

> Please enter your number: 
>       1 2 3 4 5 q
>       Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
>       at Arraylist1.main(Arraylist1.java:13)

why am i getting this error as i see everything is coded properly an the some other data(in this case q) is been added as a input to terminate the arraylist loop,still getting the error

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you input "q"? Why do you think that would happen?

Comment: q will terminate the while loop.

Comment: Don't ignore the other question :)

Comment: loop will terminate cause its getting the data other then defined

Comment: @shmosel I like the way you phrased it. I am so tempted to type out the code in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hasNextDouble()` instead of `hasNext()` for the while loop.